# Generate an exponential distribution given percentile ranks in R

Tags: r, statistics

Since my first question was not clear, let's try this again. Suppose I know this about my underlying population.

Range:        % of Pop.

0-250:        35.7%

250-500:       29.8%

500-1,000:     21.0%

1,000-2,000:   9.8%

2,000-5,000:   3.3%

5,000+:        0.5%

If I wanted to generate a population of 1000 variables that mimicked this distribution, how would I be able to do so in R?

---

Comment: How do you know your anchors will be consistent with the exponential distribution?  I have some concern that  you do not fully  understand your question, since you cannot a priori specify a maximum value for a sample from the exponential distribution.

Nonetheless, since this an R question, not a stats question, I suggest you look at the `rexp` function, which generates a stream of pseudo-random numbers from an exponential distribution with rate $1/lambda$.  If you wish to generate an exponential function with a desired median, 210 try using a rate constant of 210/ln(.5)

Comment: Once you know it's an exponential distribution with a certain rate parameter, then all of the expected quantiles are determined. You can't independently control them. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably should have clarified a little bit. I don't want to create an exponential distribution per se, I want to generate a series of random numbers that replicate the curve of an exponential distribution. Does that make sense?

Comment: @r-beginner yeah... You're describing sampling from an exponential distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to solve the statistics problem - that of estimating the parameter for the exponential distribution that best matches the data. This is the harder part (though it's not too bad).

I'm going to proceed as if the table were based on a sample; if we take the population to be of size 1000, this will be about the smallest n that would be consistent with the data. This choice won't affect the estimate (e.g. doubling the sample size would make no difference). It would matter for the standard error but that's not material here.

The most widely used approach among statisticians would be to attempt to compute the maximum likelihood estimator for the parameter on that data. The data have a special structure - the binning is a kind of [*censoring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)#Types) so methods for censored data will be needed. Using packages designed for survival analysis would be one approach; R is shipped with `survival` which will do what you need. You might use the EM algorithm. You might write the likelihood explicitly and use an optimizer.

Maximum likelihood estimators have some useful properties.

[I believe in this problem however that maximizing the likelihood we get from the survival analysis will just reduce to minimizing the statistic in a goodness-of-fit version of a [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test); that is, it will correspond to minimizing -log L = Σ O log(O/E) for the usual definitions of observed (O) and expected (E) given the model. Note that we can write this in terms of proportions and pull the sample size out the front: -(1/n) log L = Σ o log(o/p) where o is the observed proportions and p is the model proportions in each bin; it has the same argmin and so the same fit independent of any n.]

You can, however, take other approaches than maximizing likelihood. For example, you could use a minimum chi-square approach on the binned data. That should work okay too; you can write the chi-squared goodness of fit statistic as a function of the exponential parameter and minimize it. This is fairly easy to do and will generally work pretty well.

Once you have a fitted parameter, you can simulate from the exponential with a call to `rexp`. You can bin it if you need and so forth.

---

Here's a demonstration of minimum chi-squared. If we were to write a chi-squared statistic in terms of counts (the usual Σ (O-E)^2 /E form), we could convert it to a chi-squared statistic in terms of proportions by pulling an n^2 out of the numerator and an n out of the denominator, leaving us with n Σ(p-e)^2/e where p's are the observed proportions and e's are expected proportions. We can just drop the "n" without affecting the argmin and just proceed from there (so for this kind of fit we don't need an assumed sample size after all, though the resulting loss is no longer an actual chi-squared statistic).

We also have two different parameterizations in common use, the scale parameterization f(x;µ) = 1/µ exp(-x/µ); x>0; µ>0  and the rate parameterization f(x;λ) = λ exp(-λx); x>0 λ>0. These are easy to convert between so we can use whichever we like. I prefer the scale.

What are our expected proportions in each bin? For a lower bin of l and an upper bin of u we have a proportion of exp(-l/mu) - exp(-u/mu).

```
valrange <- c(0,250,500,1000,2000,5000,Inf)
l <- valrange[-length(valrange)]
u <- valrange[-1]
p <- c(.357,.298,.210,.098,.033,.005)
ch2loss <- function(mu,p,l,u) {e <- exp(-l/mu)-exp(-u/mu); sum((p-e)^2/e)}
x <- seq(500,800,10)
y <- sapply(x,ch2loss,l=l,u=u,p=p)
plot(x,y)

optim(par=650,ch2loss,method="Brent",l=l,u=u,p=p,lower=600,upper=700)
$par
[1] 659.8577

$value
[1] 0.1181881

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

(The MLE approach is roughly as easy as doing that; in fact they should also be asymptotically identical - but in small samples can differ quite a bit.)

---

Simulating:

```
  simexp <- rexp(10000,1/659.8577)
```

[image: Plot of simulated exponential with fitted parameter]

Here's the count of simulated values in the original intervals

```
  table(cut(simexp,breaks=valrange))

      (0,250]     (250,500]   (500,1e+03] (1e+03,2e+03] (2e+03,5e+03] 
         3157          2106          2490          1733           505 
  (5e+03,Inf] 
            9
```

---

As you can see, the exponential fits the shape of the data more or less okay but it's pretty clear that it's not a great fit (too few points in the first two bins and the last bin, too many in the bins in between); indeed no other exponential will be a great fit.

You might consider a broader family (such as a gamma or a Weibull, for either of which the exponential is a special case), or if you only care about the proportions in the bins (and not how they're distributed within that) you could take a nonparametric approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try reformulating your question, but I am guessing you want data *drawn from* an exponential distribution with a desired median.  As @MrFlick points out correctly, once you specify one parameter, the quantiles are completely determined.

For a sample of 100 such numbers, you can use `rexp(100,rate=qexp(.5)/210)` - 
I might suggest explaining what you are trying to accomplish.  Some additional background might direct you to the question you wanted to ask.

I will update or remove this answer if it is not what you want after you've posted the needed clarification.